# How to calculate intersection of two arcs?

Tags: intersection, spherical-geometry

Given two arcs (defined by start and end points with latitude and longitude) how to check if there is intersection (cross point) and if there is -- how to calculate it?

*Calculate "manually" -- i.e. I am looking for low-level code, like JS, C#, Python or appropriate equations, nothing high-level, like `compute_intersection(a,b,c,d)`.*

Comment: Welcome back to GIS SE. PLlease take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, this problem is not yet well-defined. You need to choose between a spherical solution and a *spheroidal* one. Then you need to pick a framework, and language, and GIS software. Then you need to try to solve the task within that framework. If you then encounter a problem, GIS SE "Focused question / Best answer" model might be able to help if you document the issue (with the risk that the documentation will solve it for you).

Comment: Did you see this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/find-intercept-wgs84-coordinates-between-two-segments-defined-by-lat1-long1-and)? I found that by Googling "geodesic intersection" (without the double quotes).

Comment: @mkennedy, thank you very much! A good question for google is essential :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for [computational geometry](http://people.inf.elte.hu/fekete/algoritmusok_msc/terinfo_geom/konyvek/Computational%20Geometry%20-%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications,%203rd%20Ed.pdf) if you are looking for algorithms?

Why not use Google and search your question choosing the appropriate language you need, I'm sure something will pop up on github?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips, however those "use google" advices are rather jokes -- I use google, I cannot find anything (the closest one was the intersection of entire circles, on this forum), I ask then and I read "use google" :-).